# Babel and Deploy Nodejs to Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm a newbie nodejs. I have a trouble about deploying nodejs app to google app engine. This is my error, I have been trying to fix it but it's not work. I've installed babel.

**Bug**

> Updating service [default]...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
>   Application startup error:
>
> restaurant_api@1.0.0 prestart /app
>   npm run -s build
>
> You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in Babel 6.
>   Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the `babel-cli` package.
>
> npm uninstall babel
>
> npm install --save-dev babel-cli

**This is my package.json**

```
 "main": "dist",
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
    "build": "babel src -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start dist",
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "babel-version": "babel --version"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 7,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 1
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "express": "^4.15.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.8.5",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0",
    "pm2": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "eslint": "^3.16.1"
  }
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message - run `npm uninstall babel`, followed by `npm install --save-dev babel-cli`

Answer (score 8):

Problem is quite simple, if you notice clearly GAE, does not install dev-dependencies. So move your dev-deps above inside deps , like I did and babel no found error is gone.

```
    {
  "name": "scraping",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "Starter project for an ES6 RESTful Express API",
  "main": "dist",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
    "build": "babel src -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0",
    "start": "node dist",
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "test": "eslint src"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 7,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 1
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/developit/express-es6-rest-api.git"
  },
  "author": "Saransh  Sharma <jason@developit.ca>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "compression": "^1.5.2",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "morgan": "^1.8.0",
    "resource-router-middleware": "^0.6.0",
    "@jonstuebe/scraper": "^0.1.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/developit/express-es6-rest-api/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/developit/express-es6-rest-api#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "scraper",
    "product",
    "from",
    "amazon"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error message.

In your devDependencies section, you already have babel-cli included.
However, your dependencies section still has a reference to `"babel": "^6.23.0"`.

Either remove this line, or replace it with babel-cli, leaving you with:

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.17.0",
  "express": "^4.15.0",
  "express-jwt": "^5.1.0",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
  "mongoose": "^4.8.5",
  "passport": "^0.3.2",
  "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0",
  "pm2": "^2.4.2"
},
```

Comment: Sorry for my dump question, I have fixed by instructions **npm uninstall babel / npm install --save-dev babel-cli**, But  I had other error when I deploy to google app engine : __sh: 1: babel: not found__

Answer (score -1):

You need to install babel-cli globally, i.e. run the command "npm install babel-cli -g" as part of your build npm script, or create a pre-install script that install it if you want to keep it more organized in case you need to add more things later on.

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
"build": "npm install bable-cli -g && babel src -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0",
```